# Interactive dashboard with customization fields

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to figure out the percentages of clients who have signed up above certain thresholds for a time period of choosing.

The thresholds below are provided as examples, but I would like to have the ability to input whatever threshold I like:

% of clients >= $100 in May 2018

% of clients >= $500 in June 2018

% of clients >= $1200 YTD

% of clients >= $2000 in 2017

Sample data:

```
user_id registration_date amount
a       3/1/2018          100
b       4/2/2018          300
c       5/3/2018          600
d       5/4/2018          900
e       6/5/2018          1100
f       6/6/2018          1300
g       9/7/2017          2000
```

How would I create an interactive sheet that allows me to input my own threshold so that it spits out the % of clients above that threshold, and input a time period of my choosing?

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a numeric parameter **[threshold]**, right click and select Show parameter control,

place registration_date on filters shelf, right click and select show filter.

Now create calculation **[User %]** like

*counnt(IIF([amount] > [threshold], [user_id], NULL)) / count([user_id])*

and place it on text (mark shelf).